# Nuget Package and DLL versioning

Tags: nuget

I have installed the MVC 4 package and it has version 4.0.20710.0 .  When I compile and build, I get a different version (4.0.40804.0) in my bin folder created. How can I fix that? What would be causing this?

Comment: Are you using a nuget.config file? If so, can you post the contents of that file?

Comment: Check the path of the reference to make sure that it is using the NuGet package and not another dll from somewhere else.

Comment: hmm, when I am adding a reference, do I browse to the bin folder, or to the package? From the question I can tell you are saying I should add the reference from the package and not from the folder. Is that the right way? What is the bin folder with all the dll files for then? Even when I add the reference to the dll in the package, after compiling when the bin folder gets the wrong dll version, the code doesn't work. Having the correct dll version  in the bin folder is the key.

Comment: @Kazuo , among other lines these are in the packages.config:   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />

Comment: Can you show the csproj file in your question. Specifically the parts that reference the dll in question. adrianbanks could be correct but I think the problem is with your nuget.config file. You have it confused with your package.config file. There is an option you can set in the nuget.config file that can cause an autoupdate of a package which may be the case here. Have a look and post the contents

Comment: @Kazuo this is the path to the folder for the dll. C:\ProjectFolder\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0.20710.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll I don't see anything in the packages.config file that would indicate an autoupdate of package. Only package nodes with an id, version, and targetframework attributes.

Comment: @newcoder

Can you search your project directory for a file called nuget.config? It may even be visible at the top of your solution when viewed from visual studio .nuget\nuget.config